# Which plants live for more than one year and less than two years?

Tags: botany, taxonomy

What kinds of plants live for more than one year and less than two years? Are there any categorical or taxonomical names for such plants?

Comment: Are these homework questions? If so you should be tagging it as homework.  But please keep in mind that stackexchange sites aren't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: A biennial, then?

Comment: Hi @Problemaniac - welcome to the community.  As mentioned above please use the homework tag where possible.  Also, from a formatting standpoint the Q1/2/3 isn't necessary =)  Regarding the close motion on this question, I do agree that this is perhaps too localised.

Comment: @Rory: I suggested an edit to make the question less localised and more fit for this site.

Comment: @TimN I'm limited as to how many characters I can place in the edit approve reason box - I think that it should be up to the OP to remove the examples part of the question when and if the community closes it as too localised.  Without the removal of the middle point then the edit would meet the too minor category so unfortunately I couldn't approve it - please do keep submitting edits to other questions however =)

Comment: This is not from homework actually. I've found answers (see edit).

Comment: @Problemaniac finding answers yourself is absolutely fine =D  It might be a better idea to post them *as answers* rather than editing them into your question though, as this may be clearer to future people who may find this question by google for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plants are called **Biennial plants**.

Examples would be **carrots** or **dandelions**.